# Multiple 3-PH Inverter Control from MCU

Tags: ground, control, inverter

It's been a while and in need of some guidance please:

I have 3 inverters controlling motors via remote potentiometers. Each of the inverters uses it's own galvanically isolated internal switch mode DC supplies to give 0-10vdc which is sent to the pots for reference.

I want to be able to monitor and control the pots using MCU either by PWM or more probably an SPI Digital Pot for each.

Will a dual rail SPI Digital Pot allow me to power the MCU from a separate local DC supply without having the grounds tied together, do I need to tie the grounds together of all the supplies or...

I have read (the rather large) manual for the inverters and can't find a parameter to set an external voltage supply for the analogue inputs and am a bit stumped on how to control the external pots due to the non-common grounds.

Hope this is clear and if I have the wrong end of the stick please bash me with the right end :)

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: [HERE IS THE MANUAL IF ANYONE CAN SPOT WHAT I SHOULD DO TO USE EXTERNAL VDC](https://www.clrwtr.com/UserFiles/CT/Documents/Danfoss/Danfoss-12-Pulse-Manual.pdf)

Comment: Can you link the manuals? Perhaps a fresh pair of eyes on it would help.

Comment: @VicenteCunha Edited the post with the link to the manual and thanks for having a look :)

Comment: I would give serious consideration to using the RS485 interface. I believe I found a separate document that can help you more directly: https://inverterdrive.com/file/Danfoss-FC300-Design-Guide . Is this the same product? I think all you need to know is in there.